# Using Moq's VerifySet in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, moq

I have a function that updates a user in the asp.net membership provider.

```
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)>
Public Function EnableUser(ByVal id As String) As JsonResult
  Dim usr As StargatePortalUser = _membershipService.GetUser(id, Nothing)
  usr.IsApproved = True
  _membershipService.UpdateUser(usr)
  Dim response As New AjaxResponse(usr.UserName)
  Return Json(response)
End Function
```

I am trying to test this function to ensure the IsApproved property is set correctly

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub Service_Can_Enable_A_User_Account()
  ' Arrange
  Dim usr As New Mock(Of MembershipUser)
  usr.SetupProperty(Function(u) u.IsApproved)

  _membershipService.Setup(Function(m) m.GetUser(It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of Boolean))).Returns(usr.Object)

  Dim target As New UsersController(_membershipService.Object)
  target.ControllerContext = New ControllerContext(FakeAuthenticatedHttpContext("testuser", String.Empty, True, True, False), New RouteData, target)

  ' Act
  Dim actual As JsonResult = target.EnableUser("userId")

  ' Assert
  Assert.IsTrue(DirectCast(actual.Data, AjaxResponse).Success)
  _membershipService.Verify(Sub(m) m.UpdateUser(It.IsAny(Of MembershipUser)), Times.Once)
  usr.Verify(Function(u) u.IsApproved = True)
End Sub
```

When I try to verify that the IsApproved property has been set to True an exception is returned:

> System.ArgumentException: Expression is not a method invocation: u => (u.IsApproved == True)

There are so few examples of using Moq in VB that I can't figure this out, any help would be appreciated.

This is an ASP.NET MVC2 app in VB.NET 10 (.NET 4.0)

EDIT:

Ok, turns out it's not quite so straight forward in VB.

```
usr.Verify(Function(u) u.IsApproved = True)
```

needs to be

```
usr.VerifySet(Function(u) InlineAssignHelper(u.IsApproved, True))
```

and you need to add the following function:

```
Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
  target = value
  Return value
End Function
```

FURTHER EDIT:

Thinking around the problem I arrived at a more simple solution. I changed

```
Dim usr As New Mock(Of MembershipUser)
usr.SetupProperty(Function(u) u.IsApproved)
_membershipService.Setup(Function(m) m.GetUser(It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of Boolean))).Returns(usr.Object)
```

for

```
Dim usr As New Mock(Of MembershipUser)
usr.SetupProperty(Function(u) u.IsApproved)
Dim usrObj = usr.Object
_membershipService.Setup(Function(m) m.GetUser(It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of Boolean))).Returns(usrObj)
```

and then can replace

```
usr.VerifySet(Function(u) InlineAssignHelper(u.IsApproved, True))
```

with the more straightforward

```
Assert.IsTrue(usrOb.IsApproved)
```

Sometimes I just don't see the simple solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the following (from http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart):

> // or verify the setter directly
>   mock.VerifySet(foo => foo.Name = "foo");

Right now the thing that you're feeding in is a comparison rather than an assignment, so even if Moq did process the statement without an exception, it would still not be Doing What You Mean.

Comment: Ok, changed usr.Verify(Function(u) u.IsApproved = True) to usr.VerifySet(Function(u) u.IsApproved = True).  Exception has changed slightly to 'System.ArgumentException: Expression is not a property setter invocation.'

Comment: Hmm, running the C# through a converter gives me mock.VerifySet(Function(foo) InlineAssignHelper(foo.Name, "foo"))
I really wish Moq had some documentation in VB.

Comment: @Nick: Is `IsApproved` a Property ? The `SetupSet` stuff is specifically for that. In other words, in order to be able to mock/stub the setting of a value, it needs to be a `virtual`  (cant remember what VB calls that!) method (which the setter part of a Property is). There is no neat way to do this in C# either (I'd suggest that if the setting is important enough to be able to stub it should be exposed as a property rather than a raw assingment in the first place). I may not have read (rewad: I ahve not read) your specific code sufficiently for me to be totally correct but I assume you get it

Comment: Yeah, IsApproved is a property on MembershipUser.  I came up with a more simple solution (see above) although it was nice to get the complex solution working as well  :)

Comment: @Nick: Simple solutions FTW. In general I think as the switch over point between asserts vs mock verification in this case being when it's on an object other than my main object under test. I'd rarely have a public protocol of this nature exposed as a setter (i.e., I'd have a MarkApproved). But obviously YMMV - for all I know you dont even own the class we're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Well this may be a little late, but I was facing the same problem and the solution was way simpler then using a InlineAssignHelper method.

Just change the ***Function*** to a **Sub** and it should work.

So try this instead:

```
usr.VerifySet(Sub(u) u.IsApproved = True)
```